# Why does the 'is' operator behave differently when using the 'not' operator on it?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've noticed following phenonema while programming:

[This code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/43bnti) snippet will actually compile (to my surprise)

```
public static void Main()
{
    object obj = "some string";
    if (!(obj is string str))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hmm... we just broke space and time");
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

[This snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoJEmE) on the other hand does not compile, as with most other stuff I tried:

```
public static void Main()
{
    object obj = "some string";
    if (obj is string str == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hmm... we just broke space and time");
        return;
    }
    //CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'str'
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

---

To my question:
Why do the first code snippets compile but the second one does not? To my understanding at first `obj is string str` should be evaluated and only then will either the `!` operator or the `==` operator be evaluated, so I don't really see how this difference can make an impact.

Comment: They don't behave differently. Second is just not valid c# code.

Comment: this is not about behaviour of code (that term refers to what it does when executed), it's about what constitutes valid syntax

Comment: @Sinatr: But *why* isn't it valid code? It looks like it *should* be semantically equivalent. `if (!expression)` and `if (expression == false)` normally are, in most cases. I think it's a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: @DaisyShipton That's not what doesn't compile. What doesn't compile is the unassigned `str`, which I'm startled to find is in scope.

Comment: Maybe [you should read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No, `str` is in scope - it's just not definitely assigned.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Corrected. But anyway my compiler likes `(obj is string str == false)` just fine.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Who was that aimed at? Which part of that page addresses this question, exactly?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It was directed at OP regarding type patterns.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: That page doesn't talk about definite assignment at all, which is what this question is about. Where do you think it answers the question?

Comment: @Sinatr yeah sry, I worded it poorly

Comment: From that [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#a-nametype--type-pattern-a), the scope of `str` (in the `!( ..)` case) should be only the `if` statement (as demonstrated by the second example)

Comment: Compiler errors and warnings are just there to help you to avoid bugs. There is no guarantee that they cover every edge case. Just try to avoid edge cases then the compiler can help you best.

Comment: If you remove the `return;` part of the first statement, you will get the same "use of unassigned variable 'str'" that you get with the second one.

Comment: Interesting that if you remove the **!** from the statement and just use `if ((obj is string str))`, it also will not compile.

Comment: @HansKesting: I believe the documentation is incorrect or at least unclear. The *scope* of `str` is always the enclosing block. For example: `if (obj is string str) {} string str = "";` gives a compile-time error. It's the definite assignment that's interesting here.

Comment: @Stringfellow: Yes, it makes perfect sense for it to not compile at that point - it's entirely reasonable for it to be not definitely assigned.

Comment: I guess the compiler team simply decided that a simple `!` can be checked easily but not to evaluate any expression that comes after `==`. The costs to check this route were simply to high. Even if in this case the expression is a simple `bool`. So you see that the `!` operator should be preferred over `== false`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's more a matter of the language specification than what the compiler decides to do. In this case, section 10.4.4.28 of the ECMA C# 5 specification is relevant - that's the part about what the `!` operator does with respect to definite assignment. In particular, it inverts "definitely assigned after true expression" to "definitely assigned after false expression" and vice versa; there's no equivalent for `== false`.

Comment: I as a human can not parse "obj is string str == false". Maybe "obj is string && str == false" could be a something you might ahve intended?

Comment: Now I get it. From the .NET documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression):

> "The samples in this topic use the recommended construct where a pattern match `is` expression definitely assigns the match variable in the `true` branch of the `if` statement. You could reverse the logic by saying `if (!(shape is Square s))` and the variable `s` would be definitely assigned only in the `false` branch. While this is valid C#, it is not recommended because it is more confusing to follow the logic."